# Angular storing nested arrays in component.ts

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, components

Angular is throwing an error for my code when I try to nest an array. Can someone help me out? My code looks like this:

```
parents = {
    pfirst_name: '',
    pmiddle_name: '',
    plast_name: '',
    ...
}

students = {
    sfirst_name: '',
    smiddle_name: '',
    slast_name: '',
    ...
}

both = {
    this.parents,  
    this.students  
}
```

And I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (61:18)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|         };
|         this.both = {
|             this: .parents,
|             this: .students 
|         };
```

I also tried it a different way:

```
both = {
    parents = {
        pfirst_name: '',
        pmiddle_name: '',
        plast_name: '',
        ...
    },
    students = {
        sfirst_name: '',
        smiddle_name: '',
        slast_name: '',
        ...
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(18,9): error TS2552: Cannot find name 'parents'. Did you mean 'parent'?
src/app/app.component.ts(18,17): error TS1312: '=' can only be used in an object literal property inside a destructuring assignment.
src/app/app.component.ts(28,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'students'.
```

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: That's a nested *object*. The syntax is `{ outer: { inner: 1 } }`, note no equals signs inside the object literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an object, not an array in your first approach. Try this:

```
// Array
both = [
    this.parents,  
    this.students  
];
// Or this alternatively
both = {
    parents: this.parents,  
    students: this.students  
};
```

And in your second approch, you have to use : instead of =, like this:

```
both = {
    parents: {
        pfirst_name: '',
        pmiddle_name: '',
        plast_name: '',
        ...
    },
    students: {
        sfirst_name: '',
        smiddle_name: '',
        slast_name: '',
        ...
    }
}
```